# No results showing up AND error as well with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

So i am trying to get values that ONLY have name in role as admin
When i put the WHERE command right after the FROM command i get an error that says

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON u.uid = ur.uid INNER JOIN `role` AS `r` ON r.rid = ' at line 9
```

But when i put it in the end of the entire thing likt it is below i get no error BUT i dont get any results EITHER!

```
SELECT f.field_first_name_value,
l.field_last_name_value,
r.name,
u.name,
u.mail,
u.created
FROM `users_roles` AS `ur`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON u.uid = ur.uid
INNER JOIN `role` AS `r` ON r.rid = ur.rid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_first_name` AS `f` ON f.entity_id = ur.uid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_last_name` AS `l` ON l.entity_id = ur.uid
WHERE 'role.name' = 'admin'
```

What can i do to get what i want.

Comment: You are using double quotes around `role.name` where you intend single quotes.  That is one problem, but I'm surprised that it would generate an error.

Comment: Shouldn't this be **WHERE role.name = 'admin'**?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am not using double quotes

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query with the error is not the one he posted.

Comment: @user3204203 You should not be using _any_ quotes around it, or you should have backticks around each component.

Comment: @Barmar when i DONT use quote i get an error, i get an error with backticks as well

Comment: @Barmar when i use backticks or no quotes i get this error

    `#1054 - Unknown column 'role.name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: The error you posted was because you put `WHERE` in the wrong part of the query. It has to be after all the JOIN clauses.

Comment: That error is because you assigned an alias to the table, you have to use the alias rather than the original table name.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this error message relates to this query !?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
WHERE r.name = 'admin'
```

The way you wrote it, you were comparing two literal strings, not comparing a column to a string.

Also, you have to use `r.name` rather than `role.name` -- once you assign an alias to a table, you can't refer to the original table name.

Comment: @Barmar Perfect!, cant believe it was this simple, thank YOU!

Comment: @WBOCo. No, that would try to refer to a column named `admin`. He's looking up the ID of the role whose name is `admin`.